# Image upload by user with Servlet and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, backend

When inserting new product via a form with image, the image is first recieved as PART and then converted to INPUT STREAM and the finally to BYTE[] and that is inserted into database but the file in database shows file size few bytes only..the image is not inserted into database....some data is being inserted but no image....I am new to all this please help. User should be able to insert any images from anywhere....

**myservlet page**

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        Produkt produkt = new Produkt();
        ProduktDAO produkt_dao = new ProduktDAO();

        if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {

            SessionFactory session_factory = DatabaseConnection.getSession_factory();
            Session session = session_factory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            String produkt_kategorie = request.getParameter("produkt_kategorie");
            String produkt_preis = request.getParameter("produkt_preis");
            String produkt_code = request.getParameter("produkt_code");
            String produkt_name = request.getParameter("produkt_name");
            String produkt_einzelheiten = request.getParameter("produkt_einzelheiten");


            Part produkt_bild = request.getPart("produkt_bild");
            InputStream eingang_storm =  produkt_bild.getInputStream();
            byte[] bild_daten = new byte[(int) eingang_storm.read()];

            produkt.setProdukt_kategorie(produkt_kategorie);
            produkt.setProdukt_preis(produkt_preis);
            produkt.setProdukt_code(produkt_code);
            produkt.setProdukt_name(produkt_name);
            produkt.setProdukt_einzelheiten(produkt_einzelheiten);
            produkt.setBild_daten(bild_daten);

            produkt_dao.einfugenProdukt(produkt);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("add_new_product.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**Entity page**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int product_id;

@Column(name = "produkt_kategorie", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String produkt_kategorie;

@Column(name = "produkt_preis", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String produkt_preis;

@Column(name = "produkt_code", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String produkt_code;

@Column(name = "produkt_name", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String produkt_name;

@Column(name = "produkt_einzelheiten", nullable = false, length = 1500)
private String produkt_einzelheiten;

@Lob
@Column(name = "produkt_bild", nullable = false,columnDefinition = "longblob")
private byte[]  bild_daten;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `byte[]` conversion is wrong. You get the first byte of the `InputStream` with `read`, and use it to create an empty `byte[]` with the length of the first byte cast to `int`. This makes no sense.

Try this instead:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((nRead = eingang_storm.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
buffer.flush();
byte[] bild_daten = buffer.toByteArray();
```

This converts your `InputStream` by 1K blocks to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then copy it to a byte array.